# State values are getting update but unable to render the dashboard page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm developing the login form using React.js. Once the user has entered the correct credentials, it should navigate to the dashboard page. Below is my login component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import './login.css';
import { redirect } from "react-router-dom";
const LoginForm = () => {
    document.body.style = 'background:#20c997';
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    localStorage.setItem("authenticated",false);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const permEmail = "piyush@gmail.com";
    const permPass = "pass";

    const handleEmail = (e) => {
        setEmail(e.target.value);
    }
    const handlePassword = (e) => {
        setPassword(e.target.value);
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(localStorage.getItem("authenticated"));
        if(email===permEmail && password===permPass){
            localStorage.setItem("authenticated",true);
            navigate("/dashboard");
        }else{
            window.alert("Wrong credentials");
        }
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div className="p-5">
                <div className="container text-start w-25 bg-light text-dark h-50 p-5 border border-primary border-2 rounded">
                    <form>
                        <div className="mb-3">
                            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" className="form-label">Email address</label>
                            <input
                                type="email"
                                className="form-control border border-primary border-1"
                                id="exampleFormControlInput1"
                                placeholder="name@example.com"
                                onChange={(e) => handleEmail(e)}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="mb-3">
                            <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlInput2" className="form-label">Password</label>
                            <input
                                type="password"
                                className="form-control border border-primary border-1"
                                id="exampleFormControlInput2"
                                placeholder="password"
                                onChange={(e) => handlePassword(e)}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <button 
                        type="submit" 
                        className="btn btn-outline-primary border-1 mt-2"
                        onClick={e=>handleSubmit(e)}
                        >Submit</button>
                    </form>


                </div>
            </div>
        </>

    )
}

export default LoginForm;
```

In the above code, I'm using localStorage to update the key. Below is the dashboard component code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Dashboard = () => {
    document.body.style = 'background:white';
    const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        setData();
    }, [])
    function setData() {
        const loggedInUser = localStorage.getItem("authenticated");
        console.log(loggedInUser);
        setAuthenticated(loggedInUser);
        console.log(authenticated);
    }
    console.log(authenticated);
    if (!authenticated) {
        return <Navigate replace to="/login" />;
    }
    else {
        return (
            <>
                <h1>Hello world</h1>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

In the above dashboard code, I'm checking whether the authenticated key in localStorage is true or not, If it is then it should return the new HTML code with ''Hello World' and if it is not then it should redirect to the login page. But I'm not getting the 'Hello World' dashboard even if the authenticated key is true. I'm stuck here. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
function MyComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Code here will run after *every* render
  });
  return <div />;
}
```

As useEffect will run after render, on first render it will have "authenticate" as false, and navigate you back to Login page.

A better way to do this is this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-tdd-y6zc8q?file=/src/LoginForm.js

Here we set the initial state as whatever is in localStorage, because setting state after useEffect is problem, as we do it after a render, which navigates us back to login, and no more /dashboard code will run or render.

Comment: Your solution is working correctly, but if I opened the dashboard directly by entering the endpoint, then also the dashboard with the hello world message is getting open because the value of authenticated is true. What I want is for the dashboard page should get open only after entering the credentials. can't we set the default value of authenticated anywhere ?

Comment: Made some changes in https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-tdd-y6zc8q?file=/src/Dashboard.js

Try playing around with this, I simply set it to false on unmount of Dashboard component, Also the check of !authenticated was always going to else, as localStorage stores value as string, so check was false. 
If this doesnt help, tell me your usecase more thoroughly